# Error trying to parse settings: No data in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/CTags.sublime-settings:1:1

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, ctags, sublimetext3

I am using ubantu and trying to configure ctags on sublime text 2 for rails.
I am getting the above error message on opening my sublime text.
On re building ctags its completing within a flash without generating a .ctag file in the specified location.

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that is an empty file right now. Open the file (possibly through another editor) and insert `{}`. The settings files are JSON objects. That just looks like it's failing the JSON parse.

Answer (score 2):

You could run `cat ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/CTags.sublime-settings` to see if there is anything in the file. If there is not you could freely delete it.

Though this error could be caused by a plugin that requires some configuration looking for its preferences file and failing.